# Making The GCC C++17 Compiler The Default Compiler in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++17

I have recently installed the C++17 gcc compiler on Centos 7 and wish to make it the default compiler in my Eclipse IDE for all C++ Projects. At the moment I have to enter
the switch -std=c++17 in the compiler settings each time I create a new project. Is there a way I can set this once somewhere which will be used as the default build environment? I am using Eclipse Luna and cannot upgrade at this present time for various reasons.

Comment: What is your compiler? Is it gcc, clang, MSVC, intel or some other one? It looks like you are using gcc though.

Comment: *"I have recently installed C++17 on Centos 7"* What does that even mean? You can't install a standard. Did you just update your compiler? Same confusion seems to exist in the title, C++17 is a standard, not a compiler.

Comment: I am indeed using the gcc compiler